# What will happen when the batsman or bowler gets injured in super-over?

Tags: rules, cricket, injuries

> *Three players from the batting side will be selected to bat in the
>   super-over. If the batting side loses two wickets, their innings
>   will end. One player from the fielding team will be selected for bowling the super over.* [-iplT20wiki.com](http://iplt20wiki.com/about-super-over-super-over-in-ipl/3036/).

- What will happen if a batsman of those three, gets injured during the super-over and can't play anymore in that over?
- Will the batting side be allowed to take a fourth player to bat?
- What will happen if the bowler who bowled one or two balls in the
  super over gets injured?
- Will the bowling side be allowed to take another player to bowl?

If the answer is **No** to any two questions above then **How will the winning side be decided?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Appendix 7.5](http://www.iplt20.com/about/2013/match-playing-conditions/54/appendix-7) of the IPL playing conditions states,

> Should any player (including the batsmen and bowler) be unable to continue to participate in the Super Over due to injury, illness or other wholly acceptable reasons, the **relevant Laws and Playing Conditions as they apply in the main match shall also apply in the Super Over**.

***Bowling injury:***

As per the normal playing conditions, the bowling captain can replace an injured bowler with another bowler of his choice. This would apply to the super-over as well and a new bowler will bowl the remaining balls of the  over.

***Batting injury:***

In the super over, if one of the openers gets injured, then the third nominated batsman comes out to the middle.However, if one of the openers is already dismissed and if another batsman gets injured - it gets interesting.
According to the rules in the main match, if a team is 9 down and a batsman gets injured, the batting team will have to bring their innings to a closure as everyone else has been dismissed. Strange as it may sound, if the same rules apply to the super-over, if a nominated batsman has been dismissed and another injured, then the team forfeits the remaining balls in the over and they end up with the then prevalent score.

Another source: [Appendix 7.6](http://static.icc-cricket.com/ugc/documents/DOC_988F9785FD768E4902737F0ACA2E856B_1352699332977_153.pdf) of ICC's T20I Playing Conditions.

Comment: I think the part about the batting injury is incorrect. All 11 players are still in the team during the super over, so if an injury occurs, the batsman can simply retire not out and one of the other 9 or 8 players comes in, even if a wicket has already fallen.  There is no requirement anywhere that exactly three batsmen be nominated before the super over.  All 11 could in theory end up batting if enough injuries occur.

Comment: @PeterEisentraut Any reference to support that? 'Coz in the main match, during the last wicket stand, if one gets injured - that is the end of the innings. I would assume the same - in a super over, a wicket down (last wicket scenario) and an injury occurs, then that would be the end of the innings.

Answer (score 0):

In the main match, the innings is over because there is no one else to come in.  In the super over, there are more players available to come in.  This discrepancy happens because in the super over the number of wickets is not the same as the number of players.

Answer (score 0):

The answers are provided clearly in the ICC's Std. Playing conditions where Super Overs are included. For the part about the batsman, if a batsman is injured and cannot return to continue his innings, he shall be considered "Retired - out" and thereby one wicket would have falled if he is one of the first opening pair to come. If he is one of the second pair batting, then the innings of the batting side would conclude.

For the second part, if the bowler is incapacitated and cannot continue, the fielding side captain can get any one of the playing fielders to complete the over, provided the player is not a substitute.

For the sake of clarity: If at the end of the main match, a substitute has fielded, he can continue to field during the Super over.

Answer (score -1):

All the rules which are included in ICC about 20ininng must be for super over as well because 20over is also the end of match and super over is also

Comment: Hi. Welcome to Sports Stack Exchange. I didn't get you clearly. Can you please be a bit clear?