# Can a team use a player for both bowling and batting in super over?

Tags: rules, cricket

> *Three players from the batting side will be selected to bat in the
>   super-over. If the batting side loses two wickets, their innings
>   will end. One player from the fielding team will be selected for bowling the super over.* [- iplT20wiki.com](http://iplt20wiki.com/about-super-over-super-over-in-ipl/3036/).

Sorry for copying from [this](https://sports.stackexchange.com/q/2544/753) post.

If a team wants a player to bowl the super over and also to face the super over. Is it possible?

To be clear, for example, if RCB selects Chris Gayle and some other player to face the super over, will Gayle allowed to bowl the super over when the opponents come to face it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes** a team can use the same player for both bowling and batting in a super over.

See [APPENDIX 7 <sup>*PDF*</sup>](http://static.icc-cricket.com/ugc/documents/DOC_988F9785FD768E4902737F0ACA2E856B_1352699332977_153.pdf) for one over eliminator. There is no such rule that a team *can't* use the same player for both bowling and batting.

This even happened in the T20I match between [West Indies and New Zealand](http://www.espncricinfo.com/icc-world-twenty20-2012/engine/match/533292.html?view=tiebreaker) in the T20I world cup 2012. Where Marlon Samuels bowled the super over then batted with Chris Gayle.

Answer (score 1):

Of course Yes.

There's no rule that decides which players can be picked for bowling/batting in the Super Over. 
It's entirely left to the Captain's discretion.